# querying a array in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

```
      idarr = [1,2,3,4,5]
      for i in  range(len(idarr)):
          upload.objects.filter(idarr[i])
```

Cant we pass the idarr at one shot to the query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming that you are trying to filter all instances of `Upload` whose `id` is in the list `idarr`. If that is the case then you can go about it like this:

```
Upload.objects.filter(id__in = idarr)
```

Read the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

So much wrong in so few lines...

1. In Python, never loop through `range(len(whatever))`. Just do `for i in whatever`.
2. Assuming `upload` is a Django model, you can't just pass a value to `filter` - you need to say what you're filtering against. Presumably it's the primary key, so you want `.filter(pk=i)`.
3. If you want to filter against any of the values in a list, use `__in`: `.filter(pk__in=idarr)`.